# Inherit ApplicationController into Grape-API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, grape-api

I am working in a Rails 3 application. I have few important implementations (like setting tenant id, authentication, etc) in the ApplicationController (as before filter) class of my application. Now when I try to implement API using the Grape, I am unable to re-use the applicationController logic in Grape.

Is it possible for Grape API classes to inherit ApplicationController? In case, if I am missing something here, please do educate me.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can let a Rails controller inherit from `Grape::API`. What you could do is: create your own base API class that inherits from `Grape::API` and implement the necessary methods to mimic your `ApplicationController`.

Grape::API provides some callback-hooks, so you could set those in your base api class, like (not tested):

```
class MyAPI < Grape::API
  before do
    authenticate!
  end

  helpers do
    def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.authorize!(env)
    end

    def authenticate!
      error!('401 Unauthorized', 401) unless current_user
    end
  end
end

class ProductAPI < MyAPI
  # Your code here
end
```